# Notepad++ Remove text before characters but have 2 same characters on every line

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi masters i need your help on Notepad++ RregExpp

i have text like this :

01:example@mail.com:test

need to convert like this :

example@mail.com:test

Thank you in advance if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use expression `^...` and replace it with empty string or better with `\n` like following **(and remove the first two characters)**:

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much HarisDevel :D

Comment: This doesn't replace the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^:]+:(.+)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Make sure to have checked `Regular expresion` but NOT `. matches newline`